# How to display images stored in laravel backend in angular frontend

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript

I have one angular + laravel project. I want to show all images in one folder in angular frontend.
I can not have the solution. Where to store the images, in backend or frontend?
In case I store in backend how can I display them in frontend.
In case I store in frontend assets folder, how can I get the all file names of the assets folder.
Please help me.

Comment: If your images are static do it in frontend.

Comment: We need some code to understand better the scenario. Anyway if the images are stored in the BE they are most likely saved as BTOA, so you could do a post request, and simply populate an img tag with the BTOA received.